# Errors configuring ffmpeg on OS X El Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg so that I can convert .mp4 files to .ogv files. I have tried using Homebrew and downloading source from ffmpeg.org. I get the same errors either way and I don't even have a clue what the fundamental problem might be.

I have followed the sample from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX. Here's what I run in the shell:

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass \
--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus \
--enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
make && sudo make install
```

And here's the error:

```
ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found
```

But I have lame installed. Running:

```
brew install lame
```

returns:

```
Warning: lame-3.99.5 already installed
```

So apparently ffmpeg can't find my lame installation? I tried configuring ffmpeg with out `--enable-libmp3lame`

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass \
--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus  --enable-libtheora \
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
```

But then I get the error:

```
ERROR: libtheora not found
```

But I have already installed theora via homebrew:

```
Warning: theora-1.1.1 already installed
```

For what it's worth I had no trouble installing everything on a Mac running Yosemite. If any of you can help out at all, I'd really appreciate it. I'm at a total loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to install ffmpeg with the desired dependencies by [uninstalling Homebrew](https://superuser.com/questions/203707/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-mac-os-x-package-manager) and then reinstalling it.

Then I ran:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-vpx --with-vorbis --with-libvorbis --with-vpx --with-vorbis --with-theora --with-libogg --with-libvorbis --with-gpl --with-version3 --with-nonfree --with-postproc --with-libaacplus --with-libass --with-libcelt --with-libfaac --with-libfdk-aac --with-libfreetype --with-libmp3lame --with-libopencore-amrnb --with-libopencore-amrwb --with-libopenjpeg --with-openssl --with-libopus --with-libschroedinger --with-libspeex --with-libtheora --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-libx264 --with-libxvid
```

Which I picked up from [here](https://gist.github.com/clayton/6196167). ffmpeg was then installed without incident and I have successfully converted an .mp4 file to .ogv.

My guess is that my problem had something to do with the Mac OS X upgrade to El Capitan. I had installed Homebrew *before* upgrading OS X, but I was trying to install ffmpeg after the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem when I followed instructions from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX to compile FFmpeg on El Capitan.

And solution I found, clarifies that MacOS version is not the issue.

Solution: You need to install Xcode command line developer tools:

```
sti-eugene:~ eugene$ xcode-select --install
```

Now works fine for me.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!